# как в mpetazzoni/ttorren автоматически обновлять JProgressBar?

Tags: java

Мне надо загрузить файл по торенту на файловую систему. Я использую библиотеку  [mpetazzoni/ttorrent](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/ttorrent)
я хочу реализовать индикатор загрузки торрент файла на панеле. для отображения процесса загрузки использую `JProgressBar`.
Вопрос в том как взять данные с `Client`. что бы автоматически обновлять `JProgressBar`.
Привязки к `mpetazzoni/ttorren` нет, использую эту либу как самую легкую из тех который нашел.если знаете другую, более удобную или где есть хорошая документация - скажите.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После небольшого забега в код выяснилось, что [`com.turn.ttorrent.client.Client`](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/ttorrent/blob/master/core/src/main/java/com/turn/ttorrent/client/Client.java) наследует [`java.util.Observable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Observable.html) (первый раз вижу использование `Observable`), поэтому можно сделать так:

```
Client client = startTorrent();
client.addObserver( new Observer() {
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        Client c = (Client)o;
        // client.info() вылетает, если торрент не инициализирован
        if ( c.getTorrent().isInitialized() ) {
                    final float completion = c.getTorrent().getCompletion();
                    System.out.printf( ">>>> torrent is %.2f%% complete.%n", completion );
                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater( () -> progressBar.setValue( Math.round( completion ) ) );
                    c.info();
        }
    }
});
```

Callback будет вызываться при смене состояния торрента и при загрузке очередного куска.